# Shape key collection name

Tags: python, shape-keys

How can I call up this name (Key.001) in python?
Every object has it's own one Key name (Key, Key.001, Key.002, Key.003...)

[image: Blender File]

Here it is in the in the console. in order to show it up I had to drag the value slider of the shape key:

[image: Python console]

So what I'm asking for is what is the name of the variable that puts the "Key.001" there.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Glad you figured it out on your own. Answering your own questions is totally encouraged and even helpful for future users, but please do so in the answer section bellow. Could you edit your question and transfer the answer part to an actual answer?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I also added the basis name, shape key name and shape key index:

```
import bpy
 
#Defines the selected shape key index.
selected_shape_key_index = bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index
print("The selected shape key index is",selected_shape_key_index)
    
#Defines the selected shape key name.
selected_shape_key_name = bpy.context.object.active_shape_key.name
print("The selected shape key name is",selected_shape_key_name)
    
#Defines the selected shape key collection.
selected_shape_key_collection = bpy.context.object.active_shape_key.id_data.name
print("The selected shape key collection is called",selected_shape_key_collection)

#Defines the Basis name
basis_name = bpy.data.shape_keys[selected_shape_key_collection].key_blocks[0].name
print("The basis name is",basis_name)
```